# Automation server can't create object - Microsoft JScript runtime error

Tags: java, internet-explorer, java-web-start

I am trying to run a Java webstart application which is launched from a html page. While loading I get an alert with the message "Automation server can't create object" a couple of times after which the applications starts and works fine. The alerts come up only on one of the workstations. Any pointers on where I should look?
Regards,
Dutch

Answer (score 2):

try the following IE setting: "Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe."

Answer (score 2):

May or may not apply to your case, but there are reported problems with the JScript Runtime throwing up errors when starting up Applets or Java WebStart applications when you have specific network settings.

Every now and again, there's a Windows Update that generates such a bug and another one that follows to fix it and you'll see some of these errors. Yours might be one of these.

Usually the workaround in-between is to either:

- go to IE's Network Settings and uncheck "auto detect settings" or any PAC file setting
- or go to the Java control panel's Network Settings and disable "Use browser settings" or other settings to use a direct connection instead.

*Obviously, that workaround is only valid if you do not **have to** go through a proxy...*